# Cannot receiver Message from Wearable

Tags: android, message, wear-os

My problem is that I cannot receive messages in the handheld app from the wearable application.

The message is sent, I can debug that.
But the handheld app cannot receive it.

I added the service to the manifest file with the right intent-filter.

```
<service android:name=".receiver.WearableListener">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.MESSAGE_RECEIVED"/>
        </intent-filter>
</service>
```

I checked that the applicationId is the same in both build.gradle-files.

I really dont know why the messages cant be received...

**EDIT:**

I could receive the message on the handheld app before I switched to the new SDK when the BIND_LISTENER action was replaced by four other actions.